# Cannot resolve PlaceAutocompleteFragment with 10.2.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, google-places-api, google-places

I'm trying to add a `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` to my activity, this are all the imports I'm using:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener;
```

I was following [this tutorial](http://codesfor.in/android-places-autocomplete-example/), so initially my app gradle had `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'` with this version all the imports above work perfect, but I want to use a newer version.

The problem is that with `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.0'` none of the imports work and it cannot resolve any of those classes. Same for 9.4.0.

I have clean, rebuild and re sync the project but the error persists.
What could be wrong?

I'm using Android Studio with

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Places has split out into [its own library](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup) since the tutorial was written

Add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:10.2.4'
```